# Custom Plugin theme filter

Tags: plugin-development, page-template

I am creating custom plugin and in my plugin file I have this:

```
add_filter('page_template', 'load_tq_templates'); 
function load_tq_templates() {
    if (is_page( 'transport-quote-1' )) {
        if ( $overridden_template = locate_template( 'tq-1.php' ) ) {
           // locate_template() returns path to file
           // if either the child theme or the parent theme have overridden the template
           load_template( $overridden_template );
        } else {
           // If neither the child nor parent theme have overridden the template,
           // we load the template from the 'templates' sub-directory of the directory this file is in
           load_template( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/tq-1.php' );
        }
    }       
}
```

I've created sub-folder "themes" in my plugin directory where I have file `tq-1.php` looking like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrapper">
       <h1>THIS IS MY CUSTOM THEME FOR PAGE tq-1</h1>
    <div id="content">
               <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
               <?php the_content(); ?>
               <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>          
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Problem is that the file really get's loaded on appropriate page, BUT after it's loaded the active theme's `page.php` is loaded as  well, so I am basically getting duplicated content on front end as `tq-1.php` is loaded first and then theme's `page.php` file is loaded second.

How to avoid theme's `page.php` from being loaded after my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `page_template` is a filter, not an action. Specifically it's filtering the file path of the template to be included.

So really you shouldn't be loading anything in that callback (it's too early). Instead just return its file path.

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'load_tq_templates' ); 
function load_tq_templates( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'transport-quote-1' ) ) {

        if ( $overridden_template = locate_template( 'tq-1.php' ) ) {
            $template = $overridden_template;

        } else {
           // If neither the child nor parent theme have overridden the template,
           // we load the template from the 'templates' sub-directory of the directory this file is in
           $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/tq-1.php';
        }

    }

    return $template;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen - I guess I was too tired to note that - thanks for pointing that out !